# error when creating procedure in Mysql, how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to creating a procedure in Mysql gut I'm getting  error at line 12.

It say:

> Database changed Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'declare required_date date default
>   cast('0001-01-01' as date);
>           declare s' at line 12 ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE classicmodels.getInfo does not exist
>   +---------+ | @result |
>   +---------+ | NULL    |
>   +---------+ 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

My code:

```
use classicmodels;

delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists `getInfo` $$
create procedure getInfo(in customer_number int(11), in order_number int(11))
begin

    if order_number = 0 and customer_number != 0 THEN
        select orders.orderDate, orders.requiredDate, orders.shippedDate from orders
            inner join customers on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
            where customers.customerNumber = customer_number;
    elseif order_number != 0 and customer_number = 0 THEN
        select orders.orderDate, orders.requiredDate, orders.shippedDate from orders
            where orders.orderNumber = order_number;
    ELSEIF order_number != 0 and customer_number != 0 THEN
        declare required_date date default cast('0001-01-01' as date);
        declare shipped_date date default cast('9999-01-01' as date);

        select requiredDate into required_date, shippedDate into shippedDate from orders
            inner join customers on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
            where customers.customerNumber = customer_number and orders.orderNumber = order_number;

        if required_date = shipped_date then 
            select "dap ung tot";
        else
            select "dap ung khong tot";
        end if;
    end if;

end $$
delimiter ;

call getInfo(353,10121);

select @result;


-- C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
```

Comment: Reverse engineering your intention from non working code is tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 issues here.

1. You cannot declare variables inside conditional statements.
2. Since your variables are scalar, limit your result to 1.
3. You don't need these variables, you can substitute it with `select case` so you can get multiple rows

Here's your complete script.

```
use classicmodels;

delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists `getInfo` $$
create procedure getInfo(in customer_number int(11), in order_number int(11))
begin


    if order_number = 0 and customer_number != 0 THEN
        select orders.orderDate, orders.requiredDate, orders.shippedDate from orders
            inner join customers on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
            where customers.customerNumber = customer_number;
    elseif order_number != 0 and customer_number = 0 THEN
        select orders.orderDate, orders.requiredDate, orders.shippedDate from orders
            where orders.orderNumber = order_number;
    elseif order_number != 0 and customer_number != 0 THEN

        select case when required_date = shippedDate then 'dap ung tot' else 'dap ung khong tot' end from orders
            inner join customers on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
            where customers.customerNumber = customer_number and orders.orderNumber = order_number

    end if;

end $$
delimiter ;

call getInfo(353,10121);

select @result;
```

Comment: why it not working: ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'into shipped_date from orders
            inner join customers on customers.cust' at line 16
ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE classicmodels.getInfo does not exist```

Comment: i removed your variables, you don't need it. you can use select case